# Ocaml Type error in merge sort program

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a simple merge sort code in OCaml, which also removed duplicates.

The code that I have written is:

```
let mergesort l r = 
match l with 
    [] -> []
|   [x]-> [x]
| x::xs ->  let rec split l3 =
                match l3 with
                    []   -> ([], [])
                |   [h]  -> ([h], [])
                |   h1::h2::t -> let (left, right) = split t in
                                    (h1::left, h2::right) in
            let rec merge l1 l2 r = 
                match (l1, l2) with
                    ([], []) -> []
                |   ([a], []) -> [a]
                |   ([], [a]) -> [a]
                |   (a1::t1, a2::t2) -> if a1 = a2 then (a1::(merge (t1) t2))
                                        else if r(a1, a2) then (a2::(merge t1 (a2::t2)))
                                        else (a1::(merge (a1::t1) t2)) in
            let (l3, l4) = split l in
                merge (mergesort l3 r) (mergesort l3 r) r;;
```

I am getting following type error in my merge function:

|(a1::t1, a2::t2) -> if a1 = a2 then

> (a1::(merge (t1) t2))

Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b list
       but an expression was expected of type 'b list

I have no idea why I am getting this error, as all the branches in merge are returning the list of same type.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: `merge` takes 3 arguments; you're calling it with 2.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel stupid now that I missed such a trivial thing..

Comment: I think you have a bug in the merge case when a1 != a2 for both the < and > case. It should be `(a2::(merge t1 (a1::t2)))` and `(a1::(merge (a2::t1) t2))`. You can also write this better using `| (a1::t1 as left, a2::t2 as right) -> ...` and using left/reight later. This saves the compiler form allocating a new list for the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues in your code:

- As mentioned in the comments, the `merge` function has 3 parameters, but you call it with 2,
- the `mergesort` function is called recursively, yet it is not declared `rec`ursive.

Here's an [existing implementation](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Merge_sort#OCaml).

Comment: It would also probably make more sense to declare `split` and `merge` as toplevel functions rather than local definitions.

Comment: Indeed, if these functionalities are likely to come up again somewhere.